# ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table

Tags: mysql, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm unable to create a table on my database," Unsuccessful: create table option (option_id integer not null auto_increment, department_department_id integer, primary key (option_id))"

I'm using RedHat Jboss Developer Studio, MySQL and Apache 3.3, I didn't understand the error.

this is the entity that has a problem to be created as a table in the database, though I have tried with other entities and I had no problem.

```
package tn.esprit.student_placement_platform.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Option
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="option")
public class Option implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="option_id")
    private int option_id;

    public Option() {

    }
```

this is my console

```
13:09:58,300 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
13:09:58,589 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
13:09:58,668 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) starting
13:10:00,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
13:10:00,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
13:10:00,127 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=MySQLDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
13:10:00,127 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=MySqlDSSemester2' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
13:10:00,127 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=MySqlDSStudentPP' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
13:10:00,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found student_placement_platform-ear.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called student_placement_platform-ear.ear.dodeploy
13:10:00,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:10:00,257 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
13:10:00,266 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
13:10:00,380 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:10:00,380 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
13:10:00,380 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
13:10:00,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:10:00,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
13:10:00,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
13:10:00,399 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
13:10:00,513 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
13:10:00,529 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
13:10:00,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.4.Final)
13:10:00,546 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
13:10:00,513 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:10:00,513 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
13:10:00,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
13:10:00,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
13:10:00,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:10:00,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
13:10:00,668 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path C:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final [Configur+®]\wildfly-9.0.1.Final/welcome-content
13:10:01,732 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
13:10:01,762 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
13:10:01,766 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
13:10:01,833 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "student_placement_platform-ear.ear" (runtime-name: "student_placement_platform-ear.ear")
13:10:01,850 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:10:01,850 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final [Configur+®]\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
13:10:01,846 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS]
13:10:01,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/MySqlDSStudentPP]
13:10:01,846 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/MySqlDSSemester2]
13:10:01,863 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:18080
13:10:02,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "student_placement_platform-ejb.jar")
13:10:02,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "student_placement_platform-web.war")
13:10:02,177 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
13:10:02,844 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for student_placement_platform-ejb
13:10:03,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'student_placement_platform-ear.ear/student_placement_platform-ejb.jar#student_placement_platform-ejb'
13:10:03,142 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: student_placement_platform-ejb
    ...]
13:10:03,383 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
13:10:03,383 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
13:10:03,387 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
13:10:03,690 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'student_placement_platform-ear.ear/student_placement_platform-ejb.jar#student_placement_platform-ejb'
13:10:04,234 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
13:10:04,685 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
13:10:04,833 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
13:10:04,868 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
13:10:05,365 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
13:10:05,365 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
13:10:05,372 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000396: Updating schema
13:10:05,409 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000261: Table found: student_placement_platform.admin
13:10:05,409 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000037: Columns: [admin_gender, admin_phonenumber, admin_username, admin_role, admin_id, admin_cin, admin_lastname, admin_name, admin_address, admin_birthdate, admin_password, admin_email]
13:10:05,409 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
13:10:05,409 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
13:10:05,454 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000261: Table found: student_placement_platform.department
13:10:05,454 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000037: Columns: [department_id, department_name, site_site_id, headofdepartment_head_of_department_id]
13:10:05,454 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_7tpjt9qrsuwrgwpi7gk2r2ev5, fk_i0rg5vsnw9610tb8w6hnch3nh]
13:10:05,454 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_7tpjt9qrsuwrgwpi7gk2r2ev5, primary, fk_i0rg5vsnw9610tb8w6hnch3nh]
13:10:05,484 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000261: Table found: student_placement_platform.head_of_department
13:10:05,484 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000037: Columns: [head_of_department_name, head_of_department_username, head_of_department_cin, head_of_department_password, head_of_department_lastname, head_of_department_address, head_of_department_gender, head_of_department_id, head_of_department_role, head_of_department_birthdate, head_of_department_email, head_of_department_phonenumber]
13:10:05,484 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
13:10:05,484 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
13:10:05,486 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000262: Table not found: option
13:10:05,503 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000261: Table found: student_placement_platform.placement_director
13:10:05,503 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000037: Columns: [placement_director_lastname, placement_director_cin, placement_director_password, placement_director_id, placement_director_phonenumber, placement_directorname, placement_director_address, placement_director_birthdate, placement_director_email, placement_director_username, placement_director_role, placement_director_hiringdate]
13:10:05,505 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
13:10:05,505 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
13:10:05,519 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000261: Table found: student_placement_platform.school
13:10:05,519 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000037: Columns: [school_email, admin_admin_id, school_id, school_address, school_phonenumber, school_name, subscription_subscription_id]
13:10:05,519 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_mhxbm11ylj3qcaxg5xqbb0o96, fk_2ywkie89vyyvmhyc7iseqqjq7]
13:10:05,519 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_mhxbm11ylj3qcaxg5xqbb0o96, fk_2ywkie89vyyvmhyc7iseqqjq7, primary]
13:10:05,533 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000261: Table found: student_placement_platform.site
13:10:05,533 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000037: Columns: [site_name, site_address, site_id, placementdirector_placement_director_id, school_school_id]
13:10:05,533 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_2012bhpf8nikltxldidgju4g7, fk_3ekyu5v3yx6fdaxb1a456lgxv]
13:10:05,533 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_2012bhpf8nikltxldidgju4g7, fk_3ekyu5v3yx6fdaxb1a456lgxv, primary]
13:10:05,549 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000261: Table found: student_placement_platform.subscription
13:10:05,550 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000037: Columns: [subscription_id, subscription_academic_year, subscription_payment_type, subscription_payment_amount, subscription_date]
13:10:05,550 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
13:10:05,550 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
13:10:05,551 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000262: Table not found: option
13:10:05,554 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000262: Table not found: option
13:10:05,567 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table option (option_id integer not null auto_increment, primary key (option_id))
13:10:05,567 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option (
        option_id integer not null auto_increment,
        primary key ' at line 1
13:10:05,567 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000232: Schema update complete
13:10:05,833 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.11-jbossorg-1 20150505-1501 for context '/student_placement_platform-web'
13:10:07,142 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Running on PrimeFaces 5.3
13:10:07,171 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /student_placement_platform-web
13:10:07,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "student_placement_platform-ear.ear" (runtime-name : "student_placement_platform-ear.ear")
13:10:07,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:19990/management
13:10:07,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:19990
13:10:07,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started in 9709ms - Started 356 of 549 services (237 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>tn.esprit</groupId>
        <artifactId>student_placement_platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>student_placement_platform-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tn.esprit</groupId>
            <artifactId>student_placement_platform-web</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tn.esprit</groupId>
            <artifactId>student_placement_platform-ejb</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.ear.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>7</version>
                    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filename>${project.artifactId}.ear</filename>
                    <port>19990</port>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a missing table. `HHH000262: Table not found: option` either create a table in the db or change hibernate property from ` <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />` to ` <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />` this will create a table for you.  reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wh

Comment: @Clover I changed the value to create, still it shows the same error, I am trying to create a table in my database.

Comment: `ERROR[org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table option add constraint FK_3upva7ihhmc1f190wht5enjbb foreign key (department_department_id) references department (department_id)`

Comment: `ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option add constraint FK_3upva7ihhmc1f190wht5enjbb foreign key' at line 1`

Comment: as per logs(correct me if i'm wrong) you have two tables. somehow the first table department_department_id is not able to access the second table's primary key which is  department_id.

Comment: @Clover, the table 'option' has department_department_id as a foreign key, all the tables that were created already got deleted somehow, plus even when I removed the relation between the two table, still, the error says that there's a problem in the primary key of the table 'option', I tried dropping the database and creating it again, same problem, as well I tried renaming the entity , the same error always.

Comment: I changed the Entity name from 'option' to 'Filiere' turns out that it is a keyword or something, thank you for helping me.